# I cannot enter the vertical line character in OSX terminal

Tags: osx, keyboard

I'm using a Mac and I'm piping some data from `curl` to `tar` and when I went to hit the <kbd>|</kbd> in the terminal I got the <kbd>o</kbd> with an umlaut. It totally works fine, as the unicode character still comes up as U+007C, which maps to the vertical line, but it doesn't display the right character.

How do I fix it to show the right character?

Comment: Possibly remap the key?  I found this https://superuser.com/questions/40000/mac-os-x-terminal-remap-command-keys

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a keyboard problem, rather it is an output problem.  Some font you're using probably has the ASCII code for vertical bar mapped to ö .  Try a different font and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: For what it's worth, I had a similar problem with terminal in VS code, where I'm using the `CaskaydiaCove Nerd Font mono` font, and the solution was to set the "Font Ligatures" option in Settings to "false".